# GADInterstitial duplicates in view hierarchy

Tags: ios, firebase, admob

I have an implementation of `GADInterstitial`

```
class AdsManager {

    let adsAppId = MY_ID
    let fullScreenAdUnitId = MY_ID

    static let manager: AdsManager = AdsManager()

    private var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

    private init () {
        createAndLoadInterstitial()
    }

    func presentInterstitial(fromViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
        if interstitial.isReady {
            interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: viewController)
        }
        else {
            print("Interstitial is not ready")
        }

        createAndLoadInterstitial()
    }

    private func createAndLoadInterstitial() {
        //TODO: replace test ad unit id with production
        interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: MY_ID)
        interstitial.load(GADRequest())
    }
}
```

and I show this ads like this:

```
func touchedButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    AdsManager.manager.presentInterstitial(fromViewController: self)
}
```

Everythink works and looks fine but when I was debugging I found something strange:

[image]

Four instances of the same view. Anyone know is it good? Or maybe I made a mistake in my `AdsManager`? Maybe Firebase implementation mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of `GADUIKitWebView`'s is dependent on the type of advertisement that is presented. A video, image, and text ad will all have different layouts. Based on the amount of memory being used I would assume it is correct.

View hierarchy of an interactive `GADInterstitial` advertisement:

[image]

Besides that, you do have a problem with your implementation. Your problem is in this function:

```
func presentInterstitial(fromViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
    if interstitial.isReady {
        interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: viewController)
    }
    else {
        print("Interstitial is not ready")
    }

    createAndLoadInterstitial() // PROBLEM
}
```

You should move `createAndLoadInterstitial()` into the `else` so you only load another `GADInterstitial` when you actually need one. For example:

```
func presentInterstitial(fromViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
    if interstitial.isReady {
        interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: viewController)
    }
    else {
        print("Interstitial is not ready")
        createAndLoadInterstitial()
    } 
}
```

In addition to this you should implement the `GADInterstitial` [delegate methods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/ad-events) and load another `GADInterstitial` only after it has dismissed the screen. For example:

```
/// Called just after dismissing an interstitial and it has animated off the screen.
func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
    print("interstitialDidDismissScreen")
    createAndLoadInterstitial()
}
```

Comment: Daniel is right, you are creating the Interstitial regardless of the conditions

Comment: Tnx for replay, I changed my implementation according your advice but  there is still four instances of `GADUIKITWebView`. I want to know if is it good.